# groovy parsing(to get the argument names in the method calls)

Tags: shell, groovy

i want to get the names of arguments passed in the groovy method calls of groovy script.(literally to parse the script).
example:-

```
(date)(getAttribute(ShippedDate)).compareTo((Date)getAttribute(OrderDate)) > 0
```

i need to get `shippedDate` and `orderDate`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain better what it is you want?  What are you starting with?  A complete Groovy Script?  What result do you want from doing what you want to do?

Comment: Sounds like you need to hunt for a groovy language parser.

Comment: @glenn jackman: yes i need something similar to a parser can i get some help about this?                                                  thank you.

Comment: @tim_yates:thank you for your response, i need all the identifiers in the groovy script including the names of function arguments that are passed in the respective methods. I am starting with a complete groovy script from which i have to extract this data.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be hidden in the groovy console. There you can access the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) from the menu via Script->Inspect Ast . In this view, you will find the parameters you are searching for.

So it seems to be possible. While searching for "groovy ast" on google, I found the following code which seems to take a script and output the AST:

http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/branches/gep-3/src/main/groovy/inspect/swingui/AstBrowser.groovy

Hope that helps!